# fahren in (die oder den) Sommerferien

Tags: grammar, preposition

Welcher Satz ist richtig?

> Ich fahre in die Sommerferien.
>
> Ich fahre in den Sommerferien.

Ich weiß, wann man nach den `Wechselpräpositionen` `Dativ` oder `Akkusativ` benutzen muss. Aber hier ist `Sommerferien` ein `Zeitraum` oder? Sollen wir hier auch die Fragen `wo` oder `wohin` stellen?

Comment: Kontext ist König. Die idealtypischen Sätze in der Antwort beschreiben sehr gut den Normalfall. Aber wenn der Gesprächsgegenstand sich bereits um eine bestimmte Reise dreht und nur der Zeitraum fraglich ist, dann kann durchaus auch nur der Zeitraum angegeben werden: "Besuchst Du deine Tante mal wieder?" - "Ja, ich fahre in den Sommerferien."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Wahl zwischen Dativ und Akkusativ ist hier sehr ähnlich wie in dem Fall, dass das Objekt ein Ort ist.

> Ich fahre mit der Bahn in die Sommerferien.

Dies berichtet von der Reise zu einem Urlaubsort.

> Ich fahre in den Sommerferien viel Fahrrad.

Dies berichtet von einer Freizeitbeschäftigung während der Ferien.

Comment: *während de`n` Ferien :)

Comment: Die Satzumstellung zw. den Beispielen ist unnötig und irritiert daher. "Ich esse Erdbeeren in den Sommerferien" bezeichnet einen Zeitraum, aber die Reise in die Sommerferien auch. Nur ist das eine der Prozess, der die Ferien erst einläutet, während das andere die ganze Phase ist. "Der Arzt sticht in die Blase". "Eiter befindet sich in der Blase".

Comment: Ich habe in Heiden Fällen die Satzstellung gewählt, die mir natürlicher erschien. Dass die jeweils andere auch möglich wäre, bestreite ich nicht.

Comment: @Sam, Siehe hier: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/waehrend_binnen_inmitten